# combo hard button to trigger a service

Tags: android

i am building an app that need a very fast shortcut to trigger my app. it must be shorter than 2sec.

specificly, i want to know is it possible to listen hard keys combo (volume up AND down) long key pressed event, to trigger my application? even if the screen is locked.

thank you.